# Measure to indicate dataset imbalance?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, statistical-significance, dataset

I have a dataset with 83% of positive class and 17% of negative class.

While this seems to be a imbalanced dataset based on outcome class proportion and features also don't show any variabity ( to differentiate these two classes).

So, I would like to know whether there is any standard measure that can indicate how imbalanced is the data?

For ex: if the measure has a value of 1, it is highly imbalanced and 0 means, it is highly balanced.

Is there anyway to find this using the python approach?

Comment: [Are unbalanced datasets problematic, and (how) does oversampling (purport to) help?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/357466/1352)

Comment: It sounds like you are asking for a universal way to translate the clear, quantitative numbers "83% and 17%" into a qualitative expression like "highly imbalanced."  That sounds like a giant step backwards.  Could you explain what the purpose of this might be?

Comment: I ask to know whether there is a standard measure (like some coefficient) which can indicate how balanced/imbalanced a dataset is. This is because, sometimes I may think that cclass proportion of 66:34 is imbalanced, but others may not feel this is heavily imbalanced. So I was thinking if there had been some objective measure to indicate balaceness of the dataset, that would be helpful...so, I can know whdther to oversample it or not..

Comment: To measure if the classes are imbalanced, why not just measure the proportion or the Bernoulli variance $p(1-p)$? Those won't put the imbalances into objective bins like "moderate imbalance" and "incontestable, severe imbalance" but such bins are not so desirable. // Regarding oversampling, please read the link in Stephan Kolassa's comment. Class imbalance is less of a problem than you think.

Answer (score 1):

Simply represent imbalance as the **percent in the minority class**.  It's simple and everyone understands it.  Do not represent it as a ratio-- this gets highly non-linear and doesn't generalize to multi-class problems.

In your case, report the minority class as 17%.   A perfectly balanced binary-class dataset would be 50%.   If we have 100 classes that are perfectly balanced, we'd expect 1% for the minority class, which is already hard; but if the minority class in this case were 0.001% we know it's even more imbalanced; it can be useful to report the **number** of train/test examples in the minority class as well.

If you can/want to report more than a single scalar, report all the percentages, sorted; (or summarize them as the min and median across the classes).  This lets us differentiate between one rare class, and several rare classes.